# New line in basic card in google actions

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I would like to have new line items in the basic card . [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses) states:

```
A limited subset of markdown is supported:
New line with a double space
*bold*
italics
```

I am able to get the bold and italics working but the new line is not working . I quite don't understand by the double space usage.

`<br>` works in the simulator but in real device it renders as `<br>`

Can someone help me in rendering multiple lines using the buildrich response ?

My code:

```
app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
        .addSimpleResponse("Simple response")
        .addBasicCard(app.buildBasicCard('L1 L2 L3')
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me works a double space enclosed by a \n

```
\n  \n
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 10):

Markdown requires that to force a line break, you need two spaces followed by a newline. So something like this in your code should work:

```
app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
        .addSimpleResponse("Simple response")
        .addBasicCard(app.buildBasicCard("L1  \nL2  \nL3")
)
```

To be clear, that is `<space><space><backslash><n>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

A limited subset of markdown is supported in google actions:

A new line with a double space like `you content  \n(content with the newline)`

for **bold** `**bold**`

and for *italic* `*italics*`

Answer (score 2):

**Following are steps to make the text for the new line in dialogflow basic card** :

1.Enter your text

2.give two spaces

3.then, (SHIFT+ENTER)

**Follow the same step for every text line.**